# As and when the lab top is open it automatically type '1111111111111111'.

Tags: windows-7, window

I am using acer laptop with window 7 basic. As and when it is on and window is displayed, it starts to type '11111111111111111' without any stop.

Any body with the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have tried looking for a stuck key, I can share that at our company we had a bunch of Acer laptops (Aspire 5 series) with a similiar defect. The keyboard seemed to send a neverending string of "1"s. Pressing "1" actually stops this but after releasing the key the behaviour returns.

This seems to be a problem not with the keyboard but with the firmware. Our solution was to return them and let Acer handle the issue -- which they did in about 4 weeks time.

Answer (score 0):

Probably key 1 is stuck.  Take the keyboard apart, and check.  If the key is stuck, fix it; otherwise, disconnect the key to see whether the problem is in the physical key or in the wiring.

Answer (score 0):

Tap Hard on key 1 to see if its stuck.

As its laptop, Taking Keyboard Apart Wont Help. See on the net how to open key for your specific keyboard type.

[Replacing Laptop Keyboard Key](http://www.fonerbooks.com/laptop15.htm)